# Choosing a non specific heatsink

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, heat, pcb-fabrication, heatsink

I am designing a PCB board, and it has lots of components on it. It has like 8 MOSFETs, diodes, fuses, current sensors, a STM32 and other components, and with an exception to a few (like mosfets and diodes) the datasheets don't include thermal resistance. To get to the point - I am getting concerned about if my PCB will get too hot, despite having more than appropriate trace specs (3oz copper rated for <20 C rise ). Is there a way to have a general heat sink that just sits on the board? Or am I better off selecting one components and attaching a heat sink to it? or sitting a heat sink on like a copper pad not connected to a component? And if I select a component, how do I decide which one?

Comment: Lots of components do not mean too much heat, you should calculate the power dissipations of components individually.

Comment: Consider arranging airflow across the board - fan and air duct may make more sense than a heatsink.

Comment: List one that doesn't have the thermal resistance stated please.

Comment: @Andyaka R-785.0-1.0  DCDC converter, MCP2551-I-SN, MCP2515-IST, ECS-160-20-5PX-TR, 74651195R terminal shank, CB1F-R-12V Relay, RC0805JR-071KL, RC0805FR-0710KL, RC0805FR-074K7L, Resistors , C0805C220J5GACTU, C0805C104Z5VACTU, C0805C102M5RACTU Capacitors, R1966IBLKBLKEP 15A rocker switch,

Comment: Capacitors don't dissipate significant power so strike that off the list. The recom regulator has in-built thermal protection. I just did start and end. Convince me you know what you are talking about and pick a component that dissipates significant heat that hasn't got a stated thermal resistance.

Comment: Your RECOM R785 has 70 K/W. Read the datasheet. Compute individual power losses per component.

Answer (score 2):

You could do a power plane on the PCB bottom side and mount it on a metal box or a metal plate which could act as a heat sink for the whole board. Then you can use thermal pads with isolation in order to avoid short circuits between different traces or components.

[image]

Comment: So I have a lot of THT components on my board. Is this still possible with THT components?

Comment: It is. See for example this picture in my answer where two MOSFET are pressing against the metal box with their drain pin and a thermal and electrically isolating pad

Comment: Ahh ok I see, thanks. Is the thermal and electrically isolating pad the white thing behind the metal pad of the MOSFET?

Comment: That should be a thermally *conductive* pad, not thermally isolating. You want as good a thermal contact to the heatsink as possible!

Comment: Yes, the white thing. It's Electrically isolating. Thermally conductive